# Is the Git staging area just an index?

Tags: git, git-index

The book Pro Git says that the staging area is just a list, or index, that says which files will be committed when a `git commit` is done, and now the name `index` is more commonly known as the "staging area".

But if we modify the file `foo.txt` that is already part of the repo, and use `git add foo.txt` to stage it, and modify the file again, now the file is both "staged" and "modified" (as seen in `git status`), and if we commit, the "staged" version will go into the commit.  The second edit won't go in.

So how can the "staging area" keep track of what the first edit was if it is just an index -- a list of files?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Index is a view of your working directory that is ready for commit. It can be seen as a pre-commit state and is not as simple as a "list of files". When you do `git add`, the file (with the change) is added to the index and the newer changes will not be see until you add them too.

Comment: This is pretty old question, but I still can't find the answer on *is the staging area and index same*? Because, everywhere I look it up, it shows, that `git add` actually adds file to the index, as well as `git add` puts the file(s) into staging area (area, where files get before committing). So, are the "index" and "staging area" concepts same or not? I think it's very important to be clear about terminology and the difference (if there is any) between these two terms.

Answer (score 5):

The `index` is like an **out basket** of completed work. At any point you can `add` a (part) completed file to that **out basket** and it will replace the previous copy with your current copy, so that when you finally decide to `commit` it will use the contents of that **out basket** (the current `index`) to create the commit.

In addition your earlier `add` will have create a blob object within the repo that can be found if required via the various logs. After a while (30 days+) it will disappear with `gc`.

Comment: I liked your example with the **out basket** but you didn't mention how that related to staging at all

Comment: @EthanDavis the Staging are is, for the most part, identical to the Index. The difference is more one of perspective. The Staging area is a conceptual view for the user, while Index is more of a Git developer viewpoint (where they keep the lists of what is in the 'staging area'). Git has a lot of things named by (and for) the devs, which then get misunderstood by users ;-)

Answer (score 4):

> So how can the "staging area" keep track of what the first edit was if it is just an index -- a list?

An index is a list of names **and pointers to content**. In books, it's page numbers. In the Git index, it's object ID's in the repository's object database.

That's what the Git index is, a pathname-indexed list of content pointers.

`git add` for some pathname is basically

```
sha=`git hash-object -w path/to/it`
git update-index --cacheinfo 100644,$sha,path/to/it
```

except `git add` checks for executable files and uses `100755` for those, and does recursive adds and checks your `.gitignore` and whatever else seems like it's usually most convenient. It's a convenience command for adding content to the object db and updating the index.

Answer (score 3):

It's an index but to a list of modification trees, not files directly. See [the different type of objects git handle](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects).

Comment: The first three words are right. The rest is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The staging area is **not** just a list, nor index, which says **which** files will be committed when a git commit is done.

**If it were that, i.e. a simple list, `git add` could never work as advertised.**

Rather, `git add` has to save the contents of the file at the time that the add command is given.  So it **snapshots** files, and then puts these snapshots into the staging area, (aka 'the index', which IMHO is really a rather poor choice for a name).

So yes, in fact, the book's statement is misleading and confusing.  *But this isn't too surprising.  Much of the git documentation is confusing and poorly thought out.*

Go ahead and mark me down.  I'm sure I'm right about this.

Comment: You're wrong about this. The index is an index. Calling it a staging area was part of the effort to explain to people who'd never encountered such a thing in a vcs before why you'd want such a thing in a vcs.

Answer (score 0):

the index is not actually a list of files that we see in the project. it's a list of `blob`s that will be present in the snapshot we're going to commit next.

consider a `blob` to be a file that contains the compressed content of a specific file, for example `foo.txt` at a specific moment. (more on that [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects))

when you add a file to staging area using for example `git add foo.txt` a new `blob` for that file is generated which contains the **content** of the file **at the moment** you added it to the staging area. we can see that by using `git ls-file -s`. we'll see something like this:

`100644 9cdf71db89dabc03936d7e685d812272e8976274 0    foo.txt`

so if we make any changes, we still have the previous content stored in a `blob` and the `index` file still has a reference to that (i.e. its SHA1 hash `9cdf71db89...`).

(the actual `blob` is stored in `.git/9c/df71db89...` and to see its content we can use ‍`git cat-file -p 9cdf71db89da`)