# What does the "Files staged in the index" view mean in sourceTree?

Tags: xcode, git, atlassian-sourcetree

Anyone use sourceTree? (hopefully on a Mac). What does the Files Staged in the index mean? I've done a commit and got my Xcode project on my bitBucket repo, and my Files in the working tree contains all my project files and that's fine, but there's nothing in the Files staged in the index, or is that normal?

Comment: For a question like this, a screenshot would've helped. But I think I can guess what you're talking about. The git index is also known as the "staging area", or "cache", where you add any modified lines of source code to be committed when you next run `git commit`.

Comment: See this question for a clarification of what the Git index (a.k.a. staging area) is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138207/is-the-git-staging-area-just-an-index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means, that part would be committed when you go for a commit. It's a good feature that git provides. Say you are working on 2 features, and by the end of the day you are complete with 1 feature code changes, and are half way for the other. You can stage the changes for the 1st feature and commit those changes, still keeping all ((both the feature changes) locally.

Read the post for better explanation: [What-stage-means-in-git-source-control?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/119790/50824)